# Add class to parent when creating an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am using the SummerNote text editor but customizing the way image uploads are handled.

I am using Laravel and have S3 image uploads working correctly.

The code I am using for the onImageUpload callback from SummerNote calls an ajax function which uploads an image and places the image inside the editor using this in the success response:

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://s3.mydomain.com/images/' + url.image.name);
$('#edit').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
```

(#edit is the name of my editor)

The issue, I am trying to replicate the Medium.com styling of their content.

I have the editor set up as 100 browser width and then my P tags have a max-width of 700px and margin of auto to centre.

When the response code adds the image, it adds it into a P tag which means the images are also 700px max width.

My aim is make them 100% width of the container but keep the text paragraphs max of 700px.

The solution I can think of is adding a class to the images parent P tag of e.g. 'has-image' and then adjusting the styling.

Any help on doing that whilst creating the image tag?

In short, how can I add a class to the parent element when creating the image element using this code (or better if have suggestion)

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://s3.mydomain.com/images/' + url.image.name);
$('#edit').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
```

Comment: How will you manage the width of **P** if image and text are in same **P** ? Should consider your solution in answer?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I don't want them to be mixed. I will be working on a way to make sure the images are in their own P tag i guess.

Comment: does `image.parent("p").addClass("hasImage");` works?

Comment: use `<figure>` as your default `<img>` container. Create conditional behavior so that if there is a `<figure>` in layout, an image will append to it.